# Dropbox api in android

Tags: android, dropbox

Have anybody write some apps with using dropbox api? I want to write application, that will be able to read/write files into Dropbox Share folder...
I've found this thread: forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=25486
and this project: http://bitbucket.org/dropboxapi/dropbox-client-java/overview
but I can't find any docs or tutorials to perform dropbox files manipulation or even adding api library...

Comment: Looks like Android Dropbox SDK documentation has been added now. One can see the 'Tutorial' and 'Docs' for Android (and some other platforms) [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers

Comment: The page says "welcome", not very much java sdk documentation. Did you find any on that website?

Comment: Huh, what were you looking at? Maybe you should use another browser. There are docs: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/docs and SDKs: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/releases

Comment: I mean Android SDK. It has absolutely no docs and in addition to that method signatures look like method(String arg0, int arg1, int arg2, String arg3). Not really helpful, is it? I could get Java SDK however, and from that GUESS Android SDK parameters meaning.